# How to use different HTTP GET request in PrimeVue Datatable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I need to use different GET requests to display in my Datatable. Both come from different tables of the Database using different requests. I'm lost of what i have to do to make this work. I know i'm using different values in the `:value` of the Datatable. The values that i want to show is the Package and Page.

```
<DataTable :value="gridData" :paginator="true" :rows="50" :rowHover="true" :loading="loading" @page="scrollUp()"
               paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
               :rowsPerPageOptions="[15,25,50]" :autoLayout="true"
               selectionMode="single" dataKey="id"
               currentPageReportTemplate="Mostrando {first} até {last} de {totalRecords} Registros"
               :filters="filters"
               class="p-datatable-customers p-datatable p-component p-datatable-hoverable-rows"
               @row-select="onRowSelect">
        <div class="p-datatable-header">
            <div class="table-header">
                Orgs
                <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                <InputText v-model="filters['global']" placeholder="Global Search"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <Button label="Novo" icon="pi pi-plus" iconPos="right" @click="goToNew"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template #empty>
            Empty
        </template>
        <template #loading>
            load
        </template>
        <Column field="name" header="Name" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
            <template #body="slotProps">
                {{slotProps.data.name}}
            </template>
        </Column>
        <Column field="trade_name" header="Trade" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
            <template #body="slotProps">
                {{ slotProps.data.trade_name }}
            </template>
        </Column>
        <Column field="created_date" header="Date" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
            <template #body="slotProps">
                {{ dateHourFormat(slotProps.data.created_date) }}
            </template>
        </Column>
        <Column field="name" header="Package" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
            <template #body="slotProps">
                {{ slotProps.data.name }}
            </template>
        </Column>
        <Column field="file_name" header="Page" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
            <template #body="slotProps">
                {{ slotProps.data.file_name }}
            </template>
        </Column>
    </DataTable>
```

```
 getAll() {
                this.customerService.getAll()
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.gridData = response;
                    }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            },
            getPackage() {
                this.operationPackage = []
                this.operationPackageService.getAllOperationPackages()
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.operationPackage = response;
                    }).catch((error) => {
                    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.details) {
                        this.$toast.add({
                            severity: 'error',
                            summary: error.response.data.details,
                            life: 5000
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.$toast.add({
                            severity: 'error',
                            summary: 'N',
                            life: 5000
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            getPage() {
                this.operationPage = []
                this.operationPackageService.getAllHtmlFiles()
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.operationPage = response;
                    }).catch((error) => {
                    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.details) {
                        this.$toast.add({
                            severity: 'error',
                            summary: error.response.data.details,
                            life: 5000
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.$toast.add({
                            severity: 'error',
                            summary: 'N',
                            life: 5000
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
```

I tried to use the same `:value` for the GET requests, but it did not worked. It shows the first value that is loaded in the mounted. If loads `getAll` first, it show the values, but if loads `getPackage`, it shows the package values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, this is how i made to show the data i wanted

```
 <Column field="name" header="Package" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
        <template #body="slotProps">
            <div v-for="item in operationPackage">
                <div v-if="slotProps.data.name === item.id">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </Column>
    <Column field="file_name" header="Page" headerClass="headerClass" bodyClass="bodyClass" :sortable="true"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
        <template #body="slotProps">
            <div v-for="item in operationPage">
                <div v-if="slotProps.data.file_name === item.id">
                    {{ item.file_name }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </Column>
```